# Ruby on Rails - POST requests too many times

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, post, shopping-cart

I have a problem with my shopping cart app: when I press the add-to-cart button, the POST request is submitted multiple times. For some reason, it is usually rising with a multiple of three. For example, the first time the POST request is sent 4 times, after refreshing 7 times, 11 times, ...

I honestly have no idea where to look for the error, but here is some code:

ApplicationController:

```
before_filter :current_delivery
def current_delivery
  if session[:delivery_id]
    @delivery = Delivery.find(session[:delivery_id])
  else
    @delivery = Delivery.create
    session[:delivery_id] = @delivery.id
  end      
 end
```

OrderItemsController:

```
  def create
    @delivery.order_items.new(order_item_params)
    @delivery.save
  end
```

ProductsController:

```
def index
  @products = Product.all
  @order_item = OrderItem.new
end
```

Products index:

```
<% @products.each do |product| %>
  <%= render "product_row", product: product %>
<% end %>
```

=> Partial product_row:

```
  <%= form_for @order_item, remote: true do |f| %>
      <%= f.number_field :quantity, value: 1, class: "form-control", min: 1 %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :product_id, value: product.id %>
        <%= f.submit "Add to Cart", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: Are you using some JS etc? You may want to try in some other browser too.

Comment: Yes: order_items/create.js.erb
=>   $(".cart-text").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'layouts/cart_text') %>")

Comment: You need to see what network calls are being made and why. There's nothing here that would trigger multiple times, so it's elsewhere in your code.

Comment: Like @tadman suggests, look at the Network tab in Chrome inspector (or your browser's equivalent) so you can see what's happening client side.  Look in your log/development.log file so you can see what's happening server side.  One of those should show you what's going wrong, then you can work out why.

Comment: @tadman On the server side nothing it seems to be working fine. On the client side I noticed the last request has a substantial larger Connecting and Receiving timing (mozilla) than the others. (I'm new to this, I don't know how to fix that..)

Comment: You need to figure out what's triggering your other calls. Something JavaScript related is probably the issue, so turn off as much of that as possible to isolate the issue.

Comment: @tadman I have tried disabling all the possible js, but the issue remains. I have however, found a clue: the number of POST request sent is equal to the sum of the GET requests made. But why? ...

Comment: If you're using a version control system, and you should be, roll back in time to see if you can narrow down when this defect was introduced.